# How to fix "Failed to get workspace folder from test item" for a Java tester project in VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have a Java project in VS Code (v.1.79.2) using the Java Extension pack (v.0.25) and the Test Runner for Java (v.0.39).

When I run the tests I get the error message "*Failed to get workspace folder from test item*". Running the normal main app works fine.

However this problem does not happen on *all* Java projects with tests. In another project the tests run fine.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an issue with VS Code related to the Electron framework when the workspace folder's path has any symlinks in it. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/1463#issuecomment-1201046418, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74104, and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/630. The issue might have to do with gtk4 ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74104#issuecomment-1175549012)).

To work around the issue, open the workspace folder using the canonical path and not the symlinked path.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a symlink error. Try using opening your directory via the absolute path on your machine.